# Child algorithm in custom Processing algorithm fails to find temporary output of previous child algorithm

Tags: pyqgis, gdal, qgis-processing

I wrote a simple custom QGIS Processing algorithm in Python:

```
from qgis.core import QgsProcessing
from qgis.processing import alg
import processing


@alg(name="test", label=alg.tr("test"), group="test", group_label=alg.tr("test"))
@alg.input(type=alg.SOURCE, types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPoint], name="POINTS_INPUT", label="Point layer")
@alg.input(type=alg.RASTER_LAYER_DEST, name="OUTPUT", label="Raster output layer")
def test(instance, parameters, context, feedback, inputs):
    """Description goes here. (Don't delete this! Removing this comment will cause errors.)"""

    buffer = processing.run(
        "native:buffer",
        {
            "INPUT": parameters["POINTS_INPUT"],
            "DISTANCE": 100,
            "OUTPUT": "memory:",
        },
        is_child_algorithm=True,
        context=context,
        feedback=feedback,
    )
    
    feedback.pushInfo("Buffering done...")
    
    rasterize = processing.run(
        "gdal:rasterize",
        {
            'INPUT': buffer["OUTPUT"],
            'BURN': 123,
            'UNITS': 1,
            'WIDTH': 10,
            'HEIGHT': 10,
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT,
        },
        is_child_algorithm=True,
        feedback=feedback,
    )

    return {"OUTPUT": rasterize["OUTPUT"]}
```

When I run it, the call to the `gdal:rasterize` algorithm fails to find its input though.

My QGIS is in German, so the error is German:

> Kann Algorithmus nicht ausführen Konnte Quelllayer für INPUT nicht
> laden: output_ac05fad6_1b89_41ba_960e_a68be241e84b nicht gefunden

What is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`processing.run()` needs the `context`, otherwise it does not know where to find the temporary data. You should always pass the `context` and `feedback` objects to the child algorithms.

```
    rasterize = processing.run(
        "gdal:rasterize",
        {
            'INPUT': buffer["OUTPUT"],
            'BURN': 123,
            'UNITS': 1,
            'WIDTH': 10,
            'HEIGHT': 10,
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT,
        },
        is_child_algorithm=True,
        context=context,  # <- this line was added
        feedback=feedback,
    )
```